# C++ Recursive binary tree

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

I have this find function, which is supposed to return a node from my tree which has the value val, but it loses the node it is meant to return and instead returns a nullptr. Why is this?

```
BinaryNode<int>* generalTree::find(int val, BinaryNode<int>* thisNode){
    if(thisNode->getItem()==val){
    return thisNode;
    }
    else{
        BinaryNode<int>* left=find(val, thisNode->getLeftChildPtr());
        BinaryNode<int>* right=find(val, thisNode->getRightChildPtr());
        if(left->getItem()==val){
            return left;
        }
        if(right->getItem()==val){  
            return right;
        }
    }    
}
```

Initially the call is made with the *rootPtr* as *thisNode*

Comment: You have to provide a minimal **working** example that demonstrates the problem. We have no idea what `BinaryNode` is, what `find()` function is and how it works, what values your tree stores, how do you call your `find` function and and therefore have no idea how to answer your question. Aside of that, just use a debugger and step through your program to see how it works, and why it does not do what you expect it to.

Comment: I see no reason why that function would ever return a null pointer.  Where are you calling it from?

Comment: @SamIam: I can give you at least one good reason why - `find` returns `nullptr` while `getItem()` method does not reference `this` pointer and even though it is theoretically an undefined behavior, it works in practice.

Comment: I'm assuming that to indicate that if a node doesn't have a left or right child node, the respective pointer will be nullptr. If you pass a nullptr into the function as thisNode, what happens?

Comment: If val's not in the tree then you'd get a nullptr surely? Have you tried printing the value of thisNode->getItem() on each iteration?

Comment: do c++ functions return null when there is no explicite `return` statement?

Comment: @SamIam, if memory serves correctly, yes. I'm calling it from three different locations, all having a segfault problem when I call their functions. DDD confirmed it is returning a nullptr in here.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem becomes apparent if you look at the control flow:

```
if (A)
    return X;
else if(B)
    return Y;
if (C)
    return Z;
```

Now, what happens if none of A, B, or C is true? Execution flows off the end, without returning *anything*. This leads to undefined behavior.

The way you've written the code is also needlessly (pointlessly) inefficient. If you don't find the desired element as the root, you search *both* sub-trees. This basically means it'll search essentially the entire tree trying to find the item, rather than making use of ordering to find the item efficiently. At least under normal circumstances, you want to compare the items to find which such-tree to search, so at any given point in the search you only search the one sub-tree that can (or could) contain the data you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The function is incorrect because there is no check whether used (or returned) node is NULL.

I would write the function the following way

```
BinaryNode<int>* generalTree::find(int val, BinaryNode<int>* thisNode)
{
    if ( thisNode == nullptr || thisNode->getItem() == val ) return thisNode;


    if ( val < thisNode->getItem() ) return find( val, thisNode->getLeftChildPtr() );
    else return find( val, thisNode->getRightChildPtr() );
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting a segmentation fault using this. It's still returning a nullptr...

Comment: In this case I think the problem in the building of the tree. Did you try to output it?

Comment: I just got it to work for the rootPtr's children, but it still seg faults when I try any other node's children